# julia throws: too few type parameters specified in "new{...}"

Tags: struct, julia

I want to make a struct that works something like `struct C` below, but where `C.a` and `C.b` are of the same type:

```
struct C
    a::Array
    b::Array
    
    function C(a, b)
        length(a) == length(b) || throw(DimensionMismatch())
        new(a, b)
    end
end
```

I thought this would be trivial to implement by doing the following:

```
struct D{T<:Int}
    a::Array{T}
    b::Array{T}
    
    function D(a, b)
        length(a) == length(b) || throw(DimensionMismatch())
        new(a, b)
    end
end
```

But it throws an error:

```
# syntax: too few type parameters specified in "new{...}" around
```

I found the beginning of a solution for this on the [julia discourse](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/how-to-resolve-syntax-too-few-type-parameters-specified-in-new/15766).

```
struct E{T<:Int}
    a::Array{T}
    b::Array{T}
    
    function E(a::Array{S}, b::Array{S}) where S<:Int
        length(a) == length(b) || throw(DimensionMismatch())
        new{S}(a, b)
    end
end
```

The error is gone. But for some reason it doesn't work with all `Int`

```
v = Array{Int64}([1,2])
w = Array{Int32}([1,2])

E(v, v)
# E{Int64}(Int64[1, 2], Int64[1, 2])

E(v, v)
# MethodError: no method matching Main.workspace321.E(::Array{Int32,1}, ::Array{Int32,1})
```

Does somebody have an idea what going on here?

Answer (score 5):

I found the problem `Int` is an alias (I think, I couldn't find it in the docs.) for `Int64`. In any case:

```
julia> Int32 <: Integer
true

julia> Int32 <: Int
false

julia> Int64 <: Int
true

julia> Int64 == Int 
true

help?> Int
search: Int Int8 Int64 Int32 Int16 Int128 Integer ...

  Int64 <: Signed

  64-bit signed integer type.
```

So this works:

```
struct E{T<:Integer}
    a::Array{T}
    b::Array{T}
    function E(a::Array{S}, b::Array{S}) where S<: Integer
        length(a) == length(b) || throw(DimensionMismatch())
        new{S}(a, b)
    end
end
```